# How to build war with spring-android-basic-auth server

Tags: spring-android

The following command lines to build the deployment artifact with the spring-android-basic-auth server module (cloned from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-android-samples/tree/master/spring-android-basic-auth) only creates a spring-android-basic-auth-server-0.1.0.jar file instead of a war file as described in its REDEME:

1. mvn clean install, or
2. gradlew build

Could anyone please let me know the way to get the server war file built?

Thanks in advance
Ray

Answer (score -1):

Try to execute with command:

```
"java -jar spring-android-basic-auth-server-0.1.0.jar"
```

This example contains a Tomcat inside.